# where can i set woocommerce to show grouped products on single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

where can i set woocommerce to show grouped products on single product page?

is there an Action like:
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );

best regards and thx for an answer - alex

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this hook:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );`

From: *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-hooks.php*

---

In *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php*, you have:

```
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

And if you want to modify the related, check out: *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php*